# Open a local HTML file with url parameters through applescript in chrome mac

Tags: html, macos, parameters, applescript

I need to open a URL in Google Chrome APP on a macbook via Terminal or Apple script with automator but I am not being able to do it (take in consideration I am a beginner):

```
file:///Volumes/HDD/Downloads/ccar.html?direct=1&macro=CCAR/Wait
```

I have the html ccar.html and I have to attach `?direct=1` and also `&macro=CCAR/Wait` parameters but it just opens the URL without the params.

If you paste the complete url `file:///Volumes/HDD/Downloads/ccar.html?direct=1&macro=CCAR/Wait` in Google Chrome it works just fine.

Any ideas?

I need to open in Google Chrome

Comment: What code do you have? Have you tried to just `tell application "Google Chrome" to tell window 1 to make new tab with properties {URL:"file:///Volumes/HDD/Downloads/ccar.html?direct=1&macro=CCAR/Wait"}`? Note that the example will only work if the first window actually exists.

Comment: I have ZERO code, that's why I am asking for help on how to write that code correctly and execute it. If I paste your code on Applescript or Terminal window I get "Command not found". Would you be so kind on helping me to write such code? I've seen posts around here that orient on how to do it but I don't know how to wirte it and I know for someone with expertise is quite simple. Thanks

Comment: For me my example code works without flaw. Do you have Google Chrome or just some version of Chromium installed? Did you properly insert my example into the Script Editor? Do you have a window open?

Comment: oooh sorry sorry.. worked perfectly on applescript! I was on terminal window. My bad. Many Many Many Thanks! Now I'll tell automator to have a google chrome window open before running this script so it works correctly. Thanks again!